# PHP ZipArchive what do status values mean?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am right at the start of trying to write some PHP code to run on a Linux box on an EC2 server that will read files from my S3 bucket, zip them then write the zip file back to the bucket.

I have instantly run in to problems with even creating a simple zip archive from some images on the local disk of the EC2 instance, I am using a script to test out the idea from the PHP manual online and also have tried out a script from David Walsh - http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php which looks like it will be great. Neither result in an actual zip file and both give me different status results -

the first snippet from the php manual (to which i add the variable $thisdir)-

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "test112.zip";
$thisdir = "/uploads/";
if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}    
$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
$zip->addFromString("testfilephp2.txt" . time(), "#2 This is a test string added as testfilephp2.txt.\n");
$zip->addFile($thisdir . "/too.php","/testfromfile.php");
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close();
?>
```

output =

> numfiles: 2 status:11

I dont see any zip file in my 'uploads' folder

The second bit of code i try ( i wont post the code here) - I pass real files and it returns

> The zip archive contains 2 files with a status of 0

What are the status messages. I have checked to see if I have the correct libraries installed by looking at the output of phpinfo(); and under the ZIP heading I see -

> Zip   enabled
> Extension Version    $Id: php_zip.c,v 1.1.2.43 2008/01/18 00:51:38 pajoye Exp $
>   Zip version     1.8.11
>   Libzip version  0.8.0-compatible

I have checked the permissions of the files PHP files with the code I am executing and they are set to 777 as is the folder I am trying to add the ziparchive to. I know that this should not remain at 777.

any ideas why I cannot see a zip file? what do the status values mean? Is there a good tutorial out there for using PHP to zip files on an Amazon S3 bucket? or a good utility to provide this functionality?

cheers

Comment: Have you fixed the issue? If yes, could you explain how? I have the same troubles...

Answer (score 14):

You can find it here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php

Error 11 is "Can't open file"

Comment: I am getting a 0 staus code, still my destination folder does not show the created file. I am using it on my LocalHost.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i got error code 11 while opening a zip file for reading. The path and permissions are OK. **I just changed the DIRECTORY SEPARATOR from back slash (\) to forward slash (/) and it worked**. The strange thing is that forward slash (/) paths are in Linux where as I am working in windows server 2003.